# "null object reference error" when trying to use TTS

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use Text-To-Speech but get the following error:

> 2020-07-26 22:58:51.876 15964-15964/ch.yourclick.kitt
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: ch.yourclick.kitt, PID: 15964
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.speak(java.lang.String, int,
> java.util.HashMap)' on a null object reference
> at ch.yourclick.kitt.MainActivity.speak(MainActivity.java:61)
> at ch.yourclick.kitt.fragments.GeneralFragment$1.onClick(GeneralFragment.java:59)

**MainActivity.java**

```java
package ch.yourclick.kitt;

import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.Locale;
import ch.yourclick.kitt.ui.main.SectionsPagerAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public TextToSpeech tts;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

        // Text to speech
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) { // <-- I never get into that if statement
                    int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
                    // Language is not supported
                    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                        Log.e("TTS", "Language not supported");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Log.e("TTS", "" + status); // Returns -1
                    Log.e("TTS", "" + TextToSpeech.SUCCESS); // Returns 0
                }
            }
        });

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Speak
     */
    public void speak() {
        String text = "Hello";
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    }

    /**
     * Turn off
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

**GeneralFragment.java**

```java
package ch.yourclick.kitt.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import ch.yourclick.kitt.MainActivity;
import ch.yourclick.kitt.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link GeneralFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class GeneralFragment extends Fragment {

    public GeneralFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @return A new instance of fragment General.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static GeneralFragment newInstance() {
        GeneralFragment fragment = new GeneralFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_general, container, false);
        Button hello = view.findViewById(R.id.hello);
        
        hello.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
                mainActivity.speak();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }


}
```

It seems like `tts` returns *null* but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following two snippets from your post:

```
// Code found in onCreate(...) in MainActivity.java
tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
    // A bunch of code here
}
```

and

```
// Code found in an OnClickListener in GeneralFragment.java
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
mainActivity.speak();
```

You're *probably* getting a `NullPointerException` due to the fact that `tts` is null when you call through to `mainActivity.speak()`.

While your intentions were good, the reason for this not working as planned is that you're actually creating a new instance of `MainActivity` that hasn't gone through the appropriate lifecycle steps, meaning that `onCreate(...)` was never called and thus `tts` was never assigned... in that specific activity instance. Worth mentioning is that the "real" activity instance your fragment is running in however *should* have it set-up correctly.

So, what's the fastest way to get it working? Well, I'd say get the current activity, cast it to `MainActivity` if possible and try to call `speak()` on that instance instead:

```
hello.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity instanceof MainActivity) {
            ((MainActivity) activity).speak();
        }
    }
});
```